# RegEx capture substrings from a multiline string and convert them to an object data strucutre

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a multiline string like this:

```
url=www.website-one.com/number&id=2222&key=rer
type=web
version=3
url=www.website-two.com/number&id=9999&key=abc
type=web
version=5
```

The list could have more lines, i.e. more lines with `URL=`.

The aim is to get this JavaScript object structure:

```
{
    "url": "www.website-one.com/number&id=2222&key=rer",
    "id": "2222",
},
{
    "url": "www.website-two.com/number&id=9999&key=abc",
    "id": "9999",
}
```

How can I achieve that in JavaScript?

If there are more `URL=` found in the list, the JSON should have those as well.

**How I would try to solve it:**

1. Capture the URLs with RegEx from the list, to just display the URLs in the list
2. Then capture from each line with RegEx with the criterion: Get everything after `url=` - write it to a string called `URL`
3. Then capture in a copy of the string `URL` RegEx with the criterion: Get everything after `ID=` until `&`

**What I have already tried**

```
function start_regex() {
    var str = `
    url=www.website-one.com/number&id=2222&key=rer
    type=web
    version=3
    url=www.website-two.com/number&id=9999&key=abc
    type=web
    version=5
  `;

    //regex show only URL until end of line
    var RegExpURLonly = /url=.*([^\n]+)/g;
    var URLonly = RegExpURLonly.exec(str);


    while (URLonly != null) {
        console.log('This is URL only: ' + URLonly[1]);
        URLonly = RegExpURLonly.exec(str);
    }

    //regex show only id
    var RegExIDonly = /id=([^&]+)/g;
    var IDonly = RegExIDonly.exec(URLonly);


    while (IDonly != null) {
        console.log('This is ID only: ' + IDonly[1]);
        IDonly = RegExIDonly.exec(str); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I tried to solve my problem since few hours, but without any success. Also I do not have a really good stuff, to show it in my question. But even that, thanks for information, I will add me findings to my quesiton.

Comment: @EmbaBakar it's ok post whatever you have tried. you don't need really good stuff. you need to show that you  tried something you put minimal effort before posting.

Comment: @CodeManiac OK, you are right, thanks for the hint. I will take care about this point in the future. But there is something like, how to convert a "string" into JSON format - where i didn't find any solution while I was research "how to do it". Im even not sure, if this is possible or not....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to start with splitting on whitespace:

```
str.split(/\s+/)
```

You can then filter the resulting array for lines that start with `url=` which will give you an array of the urls:

```js
var str = `
    url=www.website-one.com/number&id=2222&key=rer
    type=web
    version=3
    url=www.website-two.com/number&id=9999&key=abc
    type=web
    version=5
  `;

let urls = str.split(/\s+/).filter(s => s.startsWith('url='))
console.log(urls)
```

Then you can `map()` over the array and look for the `id` and return an object with the url and id:

```js
var str = `
    url=www.website-one.com/number?key=rer&id=2222
    type=web
    version=3
    url=www.website-two.com/number&id=9999&key=abc
    type=web
    version=5
  `;

let urls = str.split(/\s+/).filter(s => s.startsWith('url='))
let result = urls.map(url => {
    let regex = /[?&]id=(.+?)(&.*)?$/g
    let id = regex.exec(url)
    if (id) id = id[1]
    return {url:url.slice(4), id}     // slice(4) to remove the initial "url="
})
console.log(urls)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: OP's json doesn't contain `url=`

Comment: @MarkMeyer wow, works like a charm, thank you very much. I have learned two new methodes, like map() and split(). But as I see, the result in the `console.log(result)` this is still an array and not JSON, could that be? At least in the browser console log it displays me as an 'array'.

Comment: @EmbaBakar, It has to be an array of objects because you can't have duplicate keys in a single object. It you want a JSON string you can just `JSON.stringiffy(result)`